# Sharepoint 365 Online - Napa for teams

Tags: sharepoint-online, development-enviroment, napa

Is it possible for a team to share a Sharepoint online development site, in order to use Napa, or each team member should have its own development site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options:

- creating Shared Developer Site => Create Site Collection based on Developer Site template in your organization Office 365 preview environment. This would allow you to create Shared development environment for team based testing and deployment
  http://nikpatel.net/2012/10/11/my-first-experience-with-napa-office-365-development-tools/
- sharing existing NAPA project using the button on the left hand-side "Share Project". These are the results:
  [image]
  [image]
- Creating several Developer site collections: go to SharePoint Admin Center>New>Private site collection>Choose Developer template
- Add members to an existing Developer site collection: go to Site Settings>Site permissions>Grant permissions.  **Then everyone can create their own projects**

Comment: thanks! but my question is about sharing the developer site, so each developer would be able to create it's own Napa projects. I'm sorry if it wasn't very clear.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, you just need to invite users to the site like to any regular site. I have edited my answer.

Comment: You can share the developer site if it is properly integrated with AD. but if you are just using a site that is based on free subscription or single user licensed office 365 or msdn based subscription then you wont be able to share it.